# geocode with proxy php

Tags: php, api, maps, geocode

I'm new and I'm using maps api to geocode address. In my machine I don't have any problem. The problem is when I have a server with proxy. I tried to configure the proxy using two different functions:

```
function curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://my_proxy"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, my_port); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0); //Change this to a 1 to return headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($data);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

or

```
function curl($url)
{       
    $opts = array('http' => array('proxy' => 'tcp://my_proxy', 'request_fulluri' => true));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    return $data;
}
```

and then I'm calling that function using these lines:

```
            $address = urlencode($address);
            $data = $this->curl("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={$address}&sensor=false");
            $lat_lng = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

but I'm getting 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' error.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to use a proxy in the first place? Google's request limits are pretty generous.

Comment: What's your `$address`, how many addresses are you requesting ?

Comment: I'm requesting just one address: 'Viale Masini 4, 40126 Bologna'

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I have a server with proxy.  [...]  I'm getting 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' error.

It sounds like the proxy is used by many other people, and one of them has already exceeded the (~1000-a-day?) query limit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now the error is: While trying to retrieve the URL: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?

The following error was encountered:

    * Cache Access Denied. 

Sorry, you are not currently allowed to request:

    http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?

from this cache until you have authenticated yourself.

You need to use Netscape version 2.0 or greater, or Microsoft Internet Explorer 3.0, or an HTTP/1.1 compliant browser for this to work. Please contact the cache administrator if you have difficulties authenticating yourself or change your default password.

Comment: @Katie, that's an error message from the proxy, not from Google.  You need to contact your sysadmin.